# How to configure the remote weblogic server for Coherence checking in Oracle ADF application

Tags: oracle-adf, oracle-coherence

I am a newbie to the Coherence concept in Oracle ADF. I am learning the coherence concept and trying some sample apps. I have a requirement like, I need to cache some Object in the remote server and need to use that object instead of repeated service calls. I read some documentation on coherence and tried couple of examples but I didnt found the solution. Can someone help me out in resolving this.

Regards,
Joseph.

Answer (score 0):

See sample application here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18686_01/coh.37/e18677/gs_example.htm#COHDG5043

Also, can you send snippet of problem/error which you are getting?

Comment: Hi Ankur, I am able to do the sample application in the documentation. I used JDeveloper for checking the cached data using the below commands.               cache hello-example and list. Does this mean we successfully created cache data in Coherence server ? Also I have created the web application and deployed that in web server and I am able to retrieve the cache data using a simple client web application. For how much time the cached data will be available in server. ? What was the maximum size of data we can store using Coherence cache. ? Can you please let me know.

Comment: Joseph, please refer the post https://community.oracle.com/thread/2454952?tstart=0. If you are able to retrieve your data, yes you did it right. Limit of any cache (coherence, elastic, memcached etc.) depends on the underlying memory.